# Sort Two Dimensional Array by second column resuts

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Created my own sorting algorithm but it doesn't work.  Any advice or simpler method? Spent whole day on this ... its crazy!

sample of 2Darray

2342    **88**  98

3901    **75**  71

1444    **60**  85

5327    **95**  80

4888    **83**  100

need to sort it by 2nd column so the result looks like this

5327    **95**  80

2342    **88**  98

4888    **83**  100

3901    **75**  71

1444    **60**  85

```
for(int row = 0; row < examArray.length-1; row++){

        //this checks the second column only. I left is static under column since we only compare that column. for loop will change rows
        if(tempArray[row][1]<tempArray[row+1][1]){
            //if first final(2nd column) is LESS than 2nd final then I need to swap 1st with second using for loop. Confused here!

            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < examArray[row].length; j++){

                    //this loads NEW array with new Highest studend and copys the entire row to the first location and so on...
                    sortedExamArray [i][j] = examArray[row+1][j];
                    tempArray[i][j] = examArray[i][j];
                    sortedExamArray[row+1][j]=tempArray[i][j];
                    tempArray[row+1][j]= examArray[i][j];
              tempArray[i][j] = sortedExamArray[i][j];
```

Comment: Create a `struct` to hold the three fields and use `qsort` to sort your `struct` array.

Comment: this is little bit new, could you please show an example?

Comment: Where are you getting your input data from? Is it hard-coded?

Comment: Do you need to develop your own sorting algorithm or can you use `qsort ()`?

Comment: is own hard? if qsort does the job well then why not.

Comment: `qsort` is available in the standard libraries.